# similar to nth-child(even) for a <ul>

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I did an ng-repeat on a ul.

Obviously, I cant use nth-child(even) to apply it on ul to change the background-color of the even ul

Anyone knows something similar

Comment: NG-repeat should be on the li not the ul and for that you have ngclasseven and ngclassodd

Comment: I have an ng-repeat in my li into and another ng-repeat in my ul, but both are synchronized and am getting what I need to render

Comment: my question is more css

Comment: ngclasseven and ngclassodd or $index along with ngClass should solve any issue of that kind

Comment: @UIDeveloper take a look at my answer

Comment: **This is clearly _not_ a duplicate !** The question, that this one is supposed to be a duplicate of, is about applying classes conditionally in general (and not in the context of an `ngRepeat` directive (which offers clearly more choices). Furthermore, this one is about applying classes to even/odd nth childs and the "already answered" question (in its 18 answers) has no mention of the best options which would be `ngClassEven/Odd` and `ngRepeat`'s `$even/$odd` properties (see my answer below). This question should be reopened !

Answer (score 2):

**[`ngRepeat`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)** exposes the boolean `$even` and `$odd` properties, which you can combine with **[`ngClass`](http://code.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)**:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'some-class':$odd}">
        {{item.someText}
    </li>
</ul>
```

<sub>Note: `$even` and `$odd` are based on the currnt `$index` which is zero-based, so you might need to use `$odd` instead of `$even`.</sub>

---

Or you can use the **[ngClassEven](http://code.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassEven)** / **[ngClassOdd](http://code.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassOdd)** directives:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class-even="'some-class'">
        {{item.someText}
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/78JGW/)**.

Comment: for some reason it is not exposing the boolean $even and $odd on a ul level

Comment: @UIDeveloper: `$even` and `$odd` are exposed to the scope that `ngRepeat` creates. If you put `ngRepeat` on a `<li>` it will be exposed there; if you put `ngRepeat` on a `<ul>` it will exposed there (but keep in mind that an `ngRepeat` on a `<ul>` will create multiple `<ul>` elements).

Comment: I agree with you... ng-class-even works perfectly put for an li and not a ul for some reason

Comment: Again: If you put ngRepeat on ul it will work on a ul. If you have some code that does not seem to work, share it with us so we can find out what's wrong.

Comment: Based on your comments I realized that I did a silly mistake witch is that each ul was in a separated div, there for I am not in the case of an odd even .. thank u

Comment: @UIDeveloper: If this answer helped you solve the problem, please mark it as accepted. (Don't forget to also upvote it if you haven't already :))

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M75sc/5/)**

**html**

```
<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-init="predicate='name'; reverse=false;">Sort: predicat:{{predicate}} reverse:{{reverse}} </div>
  <div ng-click="reverse=!reverse">[change reverse]</div>
  <div ng-click="predicate='name'; reverse=!reverse;">[set predicate: name + change reverse]</div>
  <div ng-click="predicate='id'; reverse=!reverse;">[set predicate: id + change reverse]</div>
  <div ng-init="lines=[{'name':'eee', 'id':7}, {'name':'aaa', 'id':9}, {'name':'ccc', 'id':8}, {'name':'bbb', 'id':2}, {'name':'ddd', 'id':3}]">
      <ul ng-repeat="line in lines | orderBy:predicate:reverse" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
          <li >{{ line.name }}</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: this works well on the li level and I need to have odd- even on my ul

Comment: @UIDeveloper is this your requirement